# IUserPasswordStore Casting issue

Tags: c#, identity

I have this class:

```
internal class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserPasswordStore<User>, IUserLoginStore<User>
{
    public UserRepository(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(User user)
    {
        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");

        return Task.FromResult<string>(user.PasswordHash);
    }

    public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(User user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<bool>(user.PasswordHash != null);
    }

    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(User user, string passwordHash)
    {
        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");

        user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;

        return Task.FromResult<int>(0);
    }

    public Task AddLoginAsync(User user, UserLoginInfo login)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<User> FindAsync(UserLoginInfo login)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<IList<UserLoginInfo>> GetLoginsAsync(User user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task RemoveLoginAsync(User user, UserLoginInfo login)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #region NotUsed

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task CreateAsync(User user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task DeleteAsync(User user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task UpdateAsync(User user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion

}
```

and in my Service I have this:

```
public class UserService : Service<User>
{
    private readonly string companyId;

    public IPasswordHasher PasswordHasher { get; set; }
    public IIdentityValidator<string> PasswordValidator { get; set; }
    public IIdentityValidator<User> UserValidator { get; set; }
    public ClaimsIdentityFactory ClaimsIdentityFactory { get; set; }

    public virtual bool SupportsUserSecurityStamp { get { return this.Repository is IUserSecurityStampStore<User>; } }

    public UserService(IUnitOfWork uow, string companyId)
        : base (uow)
    {
        this.PasswordHasher = new PasswordHasher();
        this.UserValidator = new UserValidator(this);
        this.PasswordValidator = new MinimumLengthValidator(6);
        this.ClaimsIdentityFactory = new ClaimsIdentityFactory();

        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    private IUserPasswordStore<User> GetPasswordStore()
    {
        var userPasswordStore = this.Repository as IUserPasswordStore<User>;
        if (userPasswordStore == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException(Resources.StoreNotIUserPasswordStore);

        return userPasswordStore;
    }
}
```

the **GetPasswordStore** is the problem. **userPasswordStore** is always null, even though the repository is implementing it.

For clarity purposes, here is the service class:

```
public class Service<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IRepository<T> repository;

    protected IRepository<T> Repository
    {
        get { return this.repository; }
    }

    internal Service(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.repository = unitOfWork.GetRepository<T>();
    }
}
```

Can anyone see why **UserRepository** as **IUserPasswordStore** returns null?
I am going blind staring at it :)

Comment: You should just put a break point on on the unitOfWork.GetRepository line and see what type you are getting there. Or even on the  var userPasswordStore = this.Repository as IUserPasswordStore<User>; line and see the type prior to the cast. That will give you more insight as to why your cast is null.

Comment: do you have that class defined several times? It could be a using that is causing it (something like `using IUserPasswordStore = ...`)

Comment: BTW, in the constructor that you are showing the Repository is not set. If `this.Repository` is `null`, then `as ...` will also be `null`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Nah, the repository is set in the Service<T> class. I will have a look at putting by breakpoint where TYY said and see if I can see anything

Comment: Yeah, I have seen the problem; cheers TTY. I am just returning the Repository<T> class which is not a UserRepository